# I can not turn on the system configuration in Advanced option of Text Services and Input languages?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, software-rec

I cannot turn on the System Configuration in Advanced option of Text Services and Input languages.

When I turn off this option, and apply it, then I close it and get back. That System configuration status is still turned off.

Answer (score 0):

In the Group Policy Editor browse to User Configuration -> Administrative template -> Windows
components -> Internet Explorer -> Disable change language settings. You can enable the policy from there (This either allows or disables a user's ability to turn on/off the service)

If you are a programmer you could try using OllyDbg ([download here](http://www.ollydbg.de/)) to see what happens when the options get saved.

If you are an expert user than you could try using Process Monitor ([download here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)) to see if it has changed a setting in the Windows Registry.